# how do i escape a slash character in a WPF binding path, or how to work around?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, autogeneratecolumn

I'm just learning WPF, and I gragged a table from a datasource onto a window which generated XAML for each column.

Some of those columns had names that caused the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_Rev_UnitColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Rev/Unit}" Header="Rev/Unit" Width="SizeToHeader" />
```

This causes the column to come up blank (like me).

Comment: Have you looked at {} http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx

Answer (score 6):

On MSDN there is an [article on property paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) which has a section on escape characters:

> Inside indexers ([ ]), the caret character (^) escapes the next character.
>
> You must escape (using XML entities) certain characters that are special to the XML language definition. Use & to escape the character "&". Use > to escape the end tag ">".
>
> You must escape (using backslash \) characters that are special to the WPF XAML parser behavior for processing a markup extension.
>
> - Backslash (\) is the escape character itself.
> - The equal sign (=) separates property name from property value.
> - Comma (,) separates properties.
> - The right curly brace (}) is the end of a markup extension.

The slash is not listed here so i do not know if the backslash escape would work, but you can try.

*(How exactly do you have a property name like that? It seems to be illegal both in XML and C#)*

Comment: it comes from the name of a column name in a sql server view

Answer (score 6):

I (kind of randomly) tried:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_Rev_UnitColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=[Rev/Unit]}" Header="Rev/Unit" Width="SizeToHeader" />
```

And the result was everything worked as I expected it to.  Looking at it again, I guess H.B.'s MSDN quote tells me this.  When I read that (originally on MSDN before I even posted this question, then again here) I just didn't understand what "*Inside indexers --comma-- the caret character (^) escapes the next character*" meant.

Comment: I recently came across a similar problem. Just for completion's sake, the thing about comma and caret is that you can escape the comma if your column has it in its name, like so: `Binding={Binding Path=[Hello^, World]}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mask a path with `:` character, you can try using parenthesis char `(path)`

Example usage

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="{Binding (materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```