# PropertyPath with parenthesis with the binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am creating the binding in the code behind.

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> rows = dg1.ItemsSource.OfType<IDictionary<string, object>>();
        IEnumerable<string> columns = rows.SelectMany(d => d.Keys). Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
             col.Header = column;

             // Create a factory. This will create the controls in each cell of this
             // column as needed.
             FrameworkElementFactory factory =
                 new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));

              **Binding b = new Binding() { Path=new PropertyPath(column)};**


             b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
             b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
            // b.StringFormat = "d";
             b.Converter = new MyConverter();
             b.ConverterParameter = dg1;
             factory.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
            // factory.AddHandler(TextBox.LostFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_LostFocus));
             // Create the template itself, and add the factory to it.
             DataTemplate cellEditingTemplate = new DataTemplate();
             cellEditingTemplate.VisualTree = factory;

             col.CellTemplate = cellEditingTemplate;

             dg1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Now, if the value of the column starts with an opening `(` and if it does not contain the closing braces `)` then it gives the following error..

> *Syntax error in PropertyPath 'Unmatched parenthesis'*

You can simply reproduce it like this:

```
public Window3()
{
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Binding b = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("a(") };
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
}
```

Moreover if the `PropertyPath` has the value like `(abc)` then also the binding fails .

What could be the solution to avoid such binding issues?

**EDIT:**

Any hint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720285/how-do-i-escape-a-slash-character-in-a-wpf-binding-path-or-how-to-work-around) answer.

Comment: I completely fail to understand your point.. What do you want that binding for? what kind of property is `a(`??

Comment: Its a dynamic UI where user can add the columns and they can add any string like abc( or (abc or anything but the binding breaks with such things.

Comment: But `column` is not a property its just a string, how is it going to resovle the property using the value of a string object

Comment: When developers put together the words "Dynamic" and "UI", I immediately recognize they misunderstand or ignore the right approach (which is MVVM, DataTemplating and stuff like that) in WPF. WPF UIs are dynamic by nature, because of these aspects, and I dont see what's the point of creating a binding to an invalid property.